# How can I retrieve the output of a programmatically invoked Javadoc doclet from the caller?

Tags: java, javadoc, doclet

I am writing a tool to scrape Javadoc from pre-existing Java source files and preprocess it via a custom doclet (the specifics of the processing are not relevant). I have written the doclet, and I'm able to invoke the doclet from my code via the programmatic API as indicated in the Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/standard-doclet.html#runningprogrammatically).

It appears that this mechanism is "write-only" in the sense that the results of running the doclet, if any, cannot be transmitted back to the invoker of the execute() method through a first class Java object. Instead, I have to resort to a kludge such as writing intermediate output to a file from within the doclet and then reading that back in from my caller.

So my question: is there any way to retrieve, say, a String generated by my custom doclet directly at the invoker? For eg:

```
public void foo() {
    // Invoke my custom doclet via Javadoc programmatically
    com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(new String[] {"-d", "docs", "- sourcepath", "/home/usr/src", "p1", "p2"});

    // Access the String output of my doclet here
    String processedJavadoc = getTheOutputOfMyDoclet();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the most elegant way I could come up with to do this is to make the doclet class use a static member variable that is set to the `RootDoc` instance passed in by the Javadoc harness when it invokes the doclet's `start()` method, and then allow access to the caller to this static member via a getter. This comes with the obvious thread safety issues of using a static member, but it has worked ok for my purposes.